# What query do I have to execute to get back all of the wanted results from Memgraph's database?

Tags: cypher, graph-databases, memgraphdb

I have a node in Memgraph's database called **Page** and a relationship called **HasLink**.
What query do I have to execute to get back all of the pages that are connected with relationship **HasLink**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried running

`MATCH (p1:Page)-[link:HasLink]->(p2:Page) RETURN p1, link, p2`

And it worked. I just needed to check my node and relationship labels. Found out about this as well: Memgraph docs have [Cypher manual](https://memgraph.com/docs/cypher-manual/) with a lot of useful things for begginers.